# Clicking Lock Screen in settings closes settings with error

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

I am trying to change my Lockscreen image. So I right-click the desktop and choose `Personalization` from that right click menu. Then I am in the settings window, but on clicking `Lock screen` an exception error popup occurs talking about a string of `x000xxxx` stuff. I have no option but to click `OK` in that. Then that system settings panel just disappears it exits back to my desktop!

[image: Error]

My PC is just a home PC I've had for years & it is not in any remote network that I am aware of.

I am stuck with this constant fail when trying to change my lockscreen image like I used to be able to 1 year ago *easily*!

Germaine perhaps to this problem: I cannot get Windows updated past update version 1903  by going to windows update in settings

I just want to get back to personalising my PC right here in front of me and I know nothing of remote controlling PCs.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Your question can use a bit clarity to explain what error you're seeing. Can you maybe add screenshots of where you press Lockscreen and what error show up?

Comment: The image came in as a link (it's a limit for users with reputation), I embedded it now.

Comment: It indeed sounds like a system corruption, and a Windows upgrade would potentially mitigate it so maybe focus on that. What happens when you run the Update Assistant https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10?

Comment: Yes; Your inability to upgrade your system is likely contributing to the error. So which methods have you attempted to use to upgrade from 1903 to 22H? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Have you tried DISM and SFC ? "exception processing message 0xc0000005 parameters 0x7fff90d72d58 0x7fff90d72d58 0x7fff90d72d58 0x7fff90d72d58" https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/exception-processing-message-0xc0000005-parameters/71c3eb40-7aab-4340-b2b0-9ef73961665d

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I am stuck at some version of windows in the update process   it is Build "18362 " this I just read  from a dxdiag I ran just now

Comment: FYI  last year I despaired of windows updates two of which aborted and caused a rollback so thats twice windows updates failed

Comment: Thanks HarryMC  I will do the scannow thing very soon it takes a while doesnt it but I recall that helped very much with something else that went wrong with this old spud of a PC

Comment: @Simon you didn't answer my question about updating using the Update Assistant

Comment: @Yisroel    in the meantime I will try that Update Assistant again and let you know of the obstacle it throws up which I cant recall atm

Comment: The Obstacle is that in System settings /Windows Update
"Some settings are managed by your organisation"
is mentioned  what is that I dont understand and so I dont know how to pull up the control for that How on earth do I investigate and amend?

Comment: The Win update assistant did the job Updates are in without any rollbacks & the Lockscreen appearrs to be in order without any error

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help and advices